# Landscape server for personal use does not register clients

Tags: server, landscape

I think I have a specific problem and it may not be related to the actual Landscape installation but I don't know how to present the problem other than put it in relation to the actual landscape server which is not working.

It's all installed and up and running. When registering client the last part The Registration gives me this:

> Request a new registration for this computer now? (Y/n): Please
>   wait... We were unable to contact the server.Your internet connection
>   may be down. The landscape client will continue to try and contact the
>   server periodically

my hostname is : **linux-server.home** -> home being the local domain and I'm using the server as DNS too so I can type on a client in web browser the actual name instead of IP.

After checking logs under landscape, the **broker.log** gives me this line:

> PyCurlError: Error 51: SSL: certificate subject name
>   (linux-server.tpgi.com.au) does not match target host name
>   'linux-server.home'

as you can see there is this **linux-server.tpgi.com.au** name where **tpgi.com.au** is my ISP domain.
How can I get rid of it and change it to **home** domain ?

Thank you very much for all your input

Comment: Make sure you're not using a self-signed cert - it won't work.  If you do use a cert you generate, you'll need to generate the certificate and create yourself as a CA, and then copy the CA cert to each computer and them sign the endpoint certs with the CA signing cert.  It won't be trusted outside the computers you explicitly add the certs to though, for trusting them.

Comment: Thomas, I really appreciate your help, but could you be more specific or directive, as I have no clue where to even start. How do I generate my own certificate and let the server know that I have it and then the client ?

Comment: Not within the space allotted here.  [Go here](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation15.01) and read the "Preparing for Installation" section, and the infoblurb about custom CAs.

Comment: Also note you have to edit the Apache configuration to listen on different addresses, as well as the Landscape config

Comment: Thomas, thanks again. I didn't do anything with Apache and I think I don't have to as I have followed the link and managed to create the certificate, but unfortunately after copying to client and updating the certificates I got the same think and the log tells me this: PyCurlError: Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, the key error is:

```
certificate subject name (linux-server.tpgi.com.au)
```

"certificate subject name" coming from a cert.  In other words, you are trying to contact the server at `linux-server.home` but the cert says `linux-server.tpgi.com.au`.  Is this the case?

Unfortunately, the hostname you contact needs to match your certificate.  This is the only way that the landscape-client has to validate the landscape-server (at this point in time).

Also, I'm including another link that you will run into later if you don't have agreement with the root_url and what landscape thinks the hostname of your installation is.

References:

- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL

Comment: That's the page I was actually using, and have done everything it says. And I didn't get any error messages, so assuming I've done it correctly.

Comment: Yes that's correct that was the case, but after I've done everything from that link you have posted, I got the different error: PyCurlError: Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Comment: I would check `wget https://linux-server.home` and see what happens.

Comment: This is what happens, still the same stuff: `wget https://linux-server.home
--2015-08-26 09:25:39--  https://linux-server.home/
Resolving linux-server.home (linux-server.home)... 127.0.1.1
Connecting to linux-server.home (linux-server.home)|127.0.1.1|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify linux-server.home's certificate, issued by '/CN=linux-server.tpgi.com.au’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
 requested host name 'linux-server.home’.
To connect to linux-server.home insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.`

Comment: Right, so that will need to succeed correctly.   You might want to open up a new question on how to correctly trust a self-signed certificate in ubuntu, with just the wget example, as this question is not likely to get a lot of SSL experts looking at it.

Comment: OK thank you , will search the web first and if I'm unlucky then I'll post the question.